# Driver for Canon i-SENSYS MF3010

Tags: drivers, printing

In the specifications for 
Canon i-SENSYS MF3010 http://www.canon-europe.com/For_Home/Product_Finder/Multifunctionals/Laser/i-SENSYS_MF3010/ it is mentioned the printer is compatible with GNU/Linux.

On the download page http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/Laser/LaserBase_MF_series/i-SENSYS_MF3010.aspx?type=download&page=1 there is no driver for GNU/Linux.

Where do I find a driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find "UFRII/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux v2.70" for Canon i-SENSYS MF4010 at http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/Laser/LaserBase_MF_series/i-SENSYS_MF4010.aspx?type=download&page=1

It is compatible with Canon i-SENSYS MF3010. Unpack the zip file. Install the packages compatible with your distribution, the install the printer using CUPS as you would normally do.

Unfortunately it is non-free software, so the printer is not recommended if you are out to buy a new printer.

---

As scanner MF3010 works with Sane 1.0.24.