# Canon I sensys MF3010 driver

Tags: drivers, opensuse, scanner

I have this printer + scanner. Here ([Driver for Canon i-SENSYS MF3010](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84662/driver-for-canon-i-sensys-mf3010)) I hound very useful answer to install driver and it worked for me. As printer now it works for me but I have same 1.0.23 but it doesn't recognize it as scanner...
System opensuse 13.1

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you have SANE 1.0.23.  If you consult the list of [scanners supported by SANE 1.0.23](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-backends-1.0.23.html) and the list of [scanners supported by SANE 1.0.24](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-backends.html), you'll see that the Canon i-SENSYS MF3010 is only on the second list.  You'll need to upgrade SANE.